# Add scrollable and refreshable data table between fixedWidth widgets

Tags: flutter

Totally I need a scrollable DataTable with refresh possibility on pull down between header and footer fixed width widgets.

I have a widget, using on every page in my app. THis widget return a Scaffold with appbar and body like column (). This widget used like CommonPage(title, widgetsArrayForBodyColumn) from other widgets.
For now I need to use a follow widgets in that body:
Lookup (for filtering or for example, any fixed height widget)
DataTable (for show data)
Card (to show another data)

DataTable should be scrollable and refreshable on pull down.
I tried many different ways, but still has no success. My last solution is using stack, but list hidden beside the card.

I can't understand how to achieve my goal: have refreshing datatable between non scrollable widgets in a column.

```
class CommonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<Widget> children;

  const CommonPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.children,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
...
body: Column(children: [
FixedHeightWidget(),
PageScreen(),
]);
}
}
```

```
class PageScreen {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CommonPage(
        title: Title,
        children: [
        FixedHeightWidget(),
          PageList(),
        ],
      );
    }
}
```

```
class PageList {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//TODO Return fixedWidthWidget at top, expandedRefreshableScrollableDataTable, fixedWidthWidget at bottom
}
}
```

My current solution: (almost achieves my goal, but as mentioned card hides part of list and no ways to scroll and check bottom of the list):

```
return Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: onRefresh,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        listItems.isNotEmpty
                            ? DataTable(...)
                            : Container(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                child: Card(...),
),
),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
return Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: RefreshIndicator(
                      onRefresh: onRefresh,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [listItems.isNotEmpty
                            ? DataTable(...)
                            : Container(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
 Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                child: Card(...),
),
                ],
              ),
            );
```